# Cannot create Azure DevOps Service Connection: fields in the service connection are not expected: releaseUrl

Tags: azure, azure-devops, serviceconnection

I am using the normal browser UI to create an Azure Service Connection (Azure Resource Manager using service principal (manual)). When I enter my data and click on "verify" it says:
**Verification Succeeded**

But when I click on the button **Verify and save** it reports an error in red at the top:

> Following fields in the service connection are not expected:
> releaseUrl. Only fields that are defined in the service connection's
> contribution type as inputs can be specified.

I can also select **Save without verifiation** in the button dropdown but the same error occurs.

There is no field "`releaseUrl`" on the form... so I guess this must be some bug in the backend/API?

Comment: I had a similar issue about "scopes". I was looking at those before, somehow they were still selected even though the UI I used afterwards didn't have those fields. Cancelled, refreshed page, started again and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have entered now the same data again and the issue is gone. Apparently this was some issue that existed probably for a few hours..

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

As per @Heinzlmaen's comment, simply refreshing the page and starting again fixed it for me.

The only difference in the data between my two attempts was to change the name I gave the service connection to have spaces instead of underscores, but I very much doubt that was what cured it.

Comment: Works for me as well, just refresh the page and the issue is gone.